# c# android - SQLite database not showing in layout

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

So I have a SQLite Database which I have manually inserted the code into using

```
 public class Fixtures_SQLiteDB
{
    private string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

    public  bool createDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "SphereSports.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable <FixtureItem>();



                    //connection.Execute("Drop TABLE [Person]", "");

                    connection.Execute("CREATE TABLE [Fixture] ([FixtureID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, [CompetitionID] INTEGER NOT NULL, [DATE] DATETIME NOT NULL,[KICKOFF] DATETIME NULL, [HomeTeamID] INTEGER NOT NULL ,[AwayTeamID] INTEGER NOT NULL)", "");
                    connection.Execute(String.Format("Insert Into  [Fixture] ([CompetitionID],[Date],[KickOff],[HomeTeamID],[AwayTeamID] ) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", "2","2016-02-04","1400","1","3"), "");
                    connection.Execute(String.Format("Insert Into  [Fixture] ([CompetitionID],[Date],[KickOff],[HomeTeamID],[AwayTeamID] ) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", "4", "2016-02-04", "1400", "2", "4"), "");
                    connection.Execute(String.Format("Insert Into  [Fixture] ([CompetitionID],[Date],[KickOff],[HomeTeamID],[AwayTeamID] ) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", "5", "2016-03-04", "1400", "5", "7"), "");
                    connection.Execute(String.Format("Insert Into  [Fixture] ([CompetitionID],[Date],[KickOff],[HomeTeamID],[AwayTeamID] ) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", "1", "2016-04-04", "1400", "6", "8"), "");
                    connection.Execute(String.Format("Insert Into  [Fixture] ([CompetitionID],[Date],[KickOff],[HomeTeamID],[AwayTeamID] ) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", "3", "2016-05-04", "1400", "9", "11"), "");
                    connection.Execute(String.Format("Insert Into  [Fixture] ([CompetitionID],[Date],[KickOff],[HomeTeamID],[AwayTeamID] ) Values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", "4", "2016-06-04", "1400", "10", "12"), "");

                return true;


            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

    }

    public List<FixtureItem> selectTableFixtureItem()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "SphereSports.db")))
            {
                return connection.Query<FixtureItem>("SELECT * FROM [Fixture]", "").ToList();

            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have a ListView that should show the rows according to their columns from the table.

```
public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView txtfixID { get; set; }
    public TextView txtcompID { get; set; }
    public TextView txtdate { get; set; }
    public TextView txtkickoff { get; set; }
    public TextView txthomeID { get; set; }
    public TextView txtawayID { get; set; }

}
public class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<FixtureItem> lstFixture;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, List<FixtureItem> lstFixtures)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.lstFixture = lstFixtures;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return lstFixture.Count;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return lstFixture[position].FixtureItemID;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view_dataTemplate, parent, false);

        var txtfixID = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewFixtureID);

        var txtcompID = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewCompID);

        var txtdate = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDate);

        var txtkickoff = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewKickOff);

        var txthomeID = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewHomeID);

        var txtawayID = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewAwayID);

        txtfixID.Text = "" + lstFixture[position].FixtureItemID;
        txtcompID.Text = "" + lstFixture[position].CompetitionID;
        txtdate.Text = "" + lstFixture[position].Date;
        txtkickoff.Text = lstFixture[position].KickOff;
        txthomeID.Text = "" + lstFixture[position].HomeTeamID;
        txtawayID.Text = "" + lstFixture[position].AwayTeamID;

        return view;

    }
}
}
```

The app runs on the Android Emulator without any difficulties, but the fields that should be in the SQLite database, are not showing. Is there any reason why this is happening or is there anything I am doing wrong?

Here is more code which will hopefully help solve the issue...

```
 public class NewDatabaseActivity : Activity
{
    ListView lstData;
    List<FixtureItem> lstSource = new List<FixtureItem>();
    Fixtures_SQLiteDB db;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.upcomf);

        //Create DataBase
        db = new Fixtures_SQLiteDB();
        db.createDataBase();
        string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        Log.Info("DB_PATH", folder);

        lstData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

        LoadData();

        lstData.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
        {

            //Binding Data
            var txtfixID = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewFixtureID);
            var txtcompID = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewCompID);
            var txtdate = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDate);
            var txtkickoff = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewKickOff);
            var txthomeID = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewHomeID);
            var txtawayID = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewAwayID);


        };

    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        lstSource = db.selectTableFixtureItem();
        var adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, lstSource);
        lstData.Adapter = adapter;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class FixtureItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CompetitionID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int KickOff { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamID { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamID { get; set; }
}
public class Fixtures_SQLiteDB
{
    private string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

    public bool createDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "SphereSports.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<FixtureItem>();
                //connection.Execute("Drop TABLE [Person]", "");
                connection.CreateTable<FixtureItem>();
                List<FixtureItem> newList = new List<FixtureItem>
                {
                    //sample data
                    new FixtureItem{AwayTeamID = 2, HomeTeamID =4, Date = DateTime.Now, KickOff = 1400},
                    new FixtureItem{AwayTeamID = 2, HomeTeamID =4, Date = DateTime.Now, KickOff = 1400},
                    new FixtureItem{AwayTeamID = 2, HomeTeamID =4, Date = DateTime.Now, KickOff = 1400}

                };

                connection.InsertAll(newList);

                return true;


            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

    }

    public List<FixtureItem> selectTableFixtureItem()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "SphereSports.db")))
            {
                return connection.Table<FixtureItem>().ToList();

            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Replace class "FixtureItem", this is model of your table, and use LINQ its more comfortable and clearly. Debug your application with this code and check what return method  selectTableFixtureItem() after this changes.